# DRF Updating ManyToMany in serializer update() call

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

## The model:

```
class Dvd(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    price = models.DecimalField(...)
    sold_copies = models.IntegerField(...)
    final_value = models.DecimalField(...)

class Licence(models.Model):
    distribution = models.ForeignKey(Dvd, related_name="licence_dvd")
    percent = models.DecimalField(...)
    computed_value = models.DecimalField(...)
```

## Serializers:

```
class LicenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Licence

class DvdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movie = MovieSerializer()
    licence_dvd = LicenceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Dvd
        fields = ('id', 'price', 'sold_copies', 'final_value', 'movie', 'licence_dvd')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.price = validated_data.get('price', instance.price)
        instance.sold_copies = validated_data.get('sold_copies', instance.sold_copies)
        instance.final_value = instance.price * instance.sold_copies   # is this ok?

        # TODO recalculate the licence values

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

## The story:

The goal of this serializer is to update the `Licence.computed_value` each time when the `Dvd` changes. At the end of each year, the accountant goes through all of the movies sold that year and counts total value (`final_value`) for each of them. The `licences` are contracts between the movie makers and companies. From each `dvd` sold, the company has `xx%` money. There are many companies, so the accountant has to calculate the `xx%` (usually around 5%) from the `final_value` of the related `dvd` and save it to that particular `licence.computed_value`.
(Is that clear? If needed, I can make an example)
The basic formula is:

```
Dvd.final_value = Dvd.price * Dvd.sold_copies
Dvd.licence_dvd.computed_value = Dvd.final_value * Dvd.licence_dvd.percent
```

The first one is working, but the second one is ... tricky.
If there was only one `licence` per `dvd`, it would be easy (validated_data.pop, save the `licence`, save the `dvd`). The problem is that I have multiple `licences` in the database per `dvd`, so the `licence_dvd` returns multiple objects. 
Iterating through `validated_data['licence_dvd']` gives me:

```
OrderedDict([('percent', Decimal('0.5')), ('computed_value', Decimal('1234'))])
```

per each `licence` (this is just an example).

## Questions:

- Am I doing this right? If some values are recalculated by a formula, where the definitions and calculations should be placed? At the API / serializer / front-end level?
- What is the difference between instance and validated_data in the update function? I understand that the validated_data is validated incoming data, but when and how should I access/modify its (or instance's) variables?
- How can I modify `licence_dvd` data inside `DvdSerializer`.update function?

Thank you VERY much for any helpful information!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I could not find ManyToMany relationship in your example and so the question title seems to be misleading (it is essentially one-to-many, many licenses can refer to a single DVD). For the questions:

- I am absolutely sure that serializers is not the right place for defining business logic (and updating counters is exactly a piece of it). I would suggest to place it in views. Serializers must ONLY be used for serializing/deserializing your data (e.g., transforming it from JSON into objects and back);
- The difference between instance and validated_data is that instance is the representation of an existing row in the database you are about to change and validated_data is the data you use for update (and which arrives serialized in the updating request);
- As I mentioned above, serializers is not the right place for that.Otherwise, you have to take into account that dvd.license_dvd is essentialy a set, not a single value (indeed, in your logic each dvd can have multiple licenses). So, in order to update the licenses, you have to iterate through them:

`for license in dvd.license_dvd:
     do your updates here for each license`

If you really have only one license per DVD, consider using `OneToOneField` instead, as a more appropriate.